# Data formatting in r using sample size, mean and sample variance instead of raw data points

Tags: r, input, format

I have the following data: treatment A, sample size 6, mean 5 and sample variance 10; treatment B, sample size 5, mean 10, and sample variance 14. I need to do an F-test and a pairwise comparison. Since the data is not raw data (raw data usually contain individual data points, but my data have mean and variance), so I am not sure how to put them in R. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to run an F-test on distributional parameters. Are you certain you have the assignment right?

Comment: Did the instructor say you should use R? If you just need to use R as a calculator you can plug the numbers in and calculate the answer from the formula in your book.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is maybe more of a statistics homework question. But think -- what information do you need to calculate F? Clue: WIth what you have do you know the overall mean? WIth that can you calculate the other things you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with r2evans (see coment). But you could simulate your data if you want to. If you assume they are normaly distributed.

```
A <- rnorm(n=6, mean=5, sd=sqrt(10))
B <- rnorm(n=5, mean=10, sd=sqrt(14))
```

Now run the F-Test.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That makes sense. I wanted to see if there is any way to put distributional parameters in r, but maybe not. A <- rnorm(n=6, mean=5, sd=sqrt(10)) works well.